# What does "the seeds of change" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

**Planting the seeds of change**
The Green Wave project aims to help meet the goals of the United Nations Convention on Biological Diversity by educating young people on the importance of biodiversity. In an ambitious program, students from schools all across the world have been invited to mark the International Day for Biodiversity each year by planting a single tree of an indigenous or locally important species.

What does the headline "Planting the seeds of change" mean?

Comment: It is an often-used metaphor. Seeds grow into something, and so metaphorically they're the *beginnings* of a development.  Here, they're almost literally seeds (probably tiny saplings) and the abstract development is the gradual replenishment of native tree species.

Comment: It also has a second meaning, which is the education of young people. This education is also a kind of seed that will develop into more aware adults who can take action to protect biodiversity.

Answer (score 2):

The headline has a double meaning:

**First Meaning**

> As Tᴚoɯɐuo points out in his comment, the headline does refer to planting saplings, which will eventually lead to the replenishment of important species.

**Second Meaning**

> The headline also refers to educating young people on the importance of biodiversity. Referring to educating the young as "planting seeds" is a common metaphor. In this case, the idea is that they will grow up and develop into adults who are more aware of biodiversity and who will take action to protect it.