# The double sence of a short text question

Tags: meaning-in-context

Headline: **Planting the seeds of change.**

The Green Wave project aims to help meet the goals of the United Nations Convention on Biological Diversity by educating young people on the importance of biodiversity. In an ambitious program, students from schools all across the world have been invited to mark the International Day for Biodiversity each year by planting a single tree of an inborn of locally important species. On May, 22, these student groups will each plant their tree – uniting to send a ‘green wave’ from east to west around the planet. Promoting research and learning about nature, encouraging team-work and partnership across countries and continents, The Green Wave is taking a positive step toward maintaining biodiversity all over the world.

What does its headline really mean and what is the text about in short?

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162135/what-does-the-seeds-of-change-mean

Comment: I did not understand that text, I cannot delete it I ask again, It's not my fault, it's restriction of this Site. thanks for helping

Comment: You can add a comment beneath a comment, or under an answer, asking for further clarification. We cannot tell you "what the text is about". That's too broad. You must ask specific questions.